# How To Use Token In A Resumable Upload With Google Drive API (Python)

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I'm trying to implement resumable upload with Google Drive API via Python.
It's important it will be resumable because I need to upload a few GB every time.

So I followed [this](https://tanaikech.github.io/2020/03/05/simple-script-of-resumable-upload-with-google-drive-api-for-python/) tutorial. Yet, I have no idea how to use my token inside *headers*.

The problem is in uploadFile() --> access_token=?

It can't be the token itself (or at least not in its usual form)

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
import json
import os
import requests
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

def auth():
    creds = None
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)
    global service
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

def uploadFile():
    access_token = ??? #As I get it, it should be a string. But how do I stringify a token?

    filename = './20200229_151839_008.jpg'
    filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)

    # 1. Retrieve session for resumable upload.
    headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token, "Content-Type": "application/json"}
    params = {
        "name": "20200229_151839_008.jpg",
        "mimeType": "image/img"
    }
    r = requests.post(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable",
        headers=headers,
        data=json.dumps(params)
    )
    location = r.headers['Location']


    # 2. Upload the file.
    headers = {"Content-Range": "bytes 0-" + str(filesize - 1) + "/" + str(filesize)}
    r = requests.put(
        location,
        headers=headers,
        data=open(filename, 'rb')
    )
    print(r.text)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: At first, I deeply apologize that my sample script was not useful for your situation. From your script, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to perform resumable file upload to Google Drive with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56780331/how-to-perform-resumable-file-upload-to-google-drive-with-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to retrieve the access token using the script of `auth()`, when your script is modified, please modify `auth()` as follows.

#### From:

```
global service
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
```

#### To:

```
global service, access_token
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
access_token = creds.token
```

- In this case, please remove `access_token = ???`. By this, the script can be run with `access_token` retrieved from `creds.token`.

#### Note:

- In this answer, it supposes that you have already been able to upload a file using Drive API. Please be careful this.
- In your script, `SCOPES` is not declared. Please be careful this.
- When I saw your script, it seems that you are using googleapis for python. In this case, you can also achieve the resumable upload using googleapis as follows. For this, please modify `uploadFile` as follows.

  ```
    def uploadFile():
        filename = './20200229_151839_008.jpg'
        metadata = {'name': '20200229_151839_008.jpg'}
        media_body = MediaFileUpload(filename, resumable=True)
        res = service.files().create(body=metadata, media_body=media_body).execute()
        print(res)
  ```

Comment: @Daniel Fridman Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.